# The Proper Way to use the Built-In dir function

Tags: python

I was reading [about pythons dir function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir).

- How do I make use of this properly?
- Which situation would I want to use it in?
- How to improve my understanding of any code using this?

```
class Turbine:
    def __init__(self, spin):
        self.spin = spin

    def __str__(self):
        return "Hello StackOverflow"

    def BladeMaterial(self):
        return self.spin * 0.7

Fan1 = Turbine(42)
print(dir(Fan1))
print(type(Fan1.spin))
print(type(Fan1.BladeMaterial))
```

In the above eg, I see that dir() prints out BladeMaterial and spin, and so I know that the class Turbine has the mentioned attributes/functions/methods in it
And that helps in understanding what the class Turbine may have to offer.
How to use this in other modules like say PyQt6

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
print(dir(QtWidgets.QProgressDialog))
```

Here as expected for such a big module, it gives a very big list.
So I can see what all functions I may be able to use with QProgressDialog

**But apart from this is there any othe way dir can help me ??**

Beyond this dir gives things I cannot hope to understand for now except the below, where i know what *doc* does and how to use help, but no clue what is ['**call**', '**class**', '**delattr**', etc which comes when print(dir(QtWidgets.QProgressDialog.showFullScreen)) etc is put.

```
print(QtWidgets.QProgressDialog.updateGeometry.__doc__)
help(QtWidgets.QProgressDialog.updateGeometry)
```

Comment: _helps in understanding what the class Turbine may have to offer_ Yeah, that's pretty much what I use it for.

Comment: I am a self taught beginner, so apologies if this seems basic. Net search did not give me sufficient answers/too advanced for me to know what __delattr__ etc does!

Comment: You can use `help()` to show the docstring comment of a function, like so `help(myobject.__call__)` (assuming such a comment exists, which is not always true)

Comment: @JohnGordon Will I be able to infer anything with those special methods __format__ etc which comes when using dir ?

Comment: Generally, I wouldn't worry about method names that start with two underscores.

Comment: @KarthiDiamond97: All the names that begin and end with `__` should be [special methods documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), that are used for various features of the language; you rarely call them directly, but they support other functionality.

Comment: Did you read the note at the end of the documentation? Unless you are physically calling the `dir` function by typing it at an interactive prompt, you are probably not using it correctly or as intended. I think of it as a tool to remind me of what I already know or can find by reading the documentation and/or source code, not something that I can learn directly from.

Comment: As the docs state, `dir` is "supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt". So you should really use it outside of that context. Probably you shouldn't use it in code you actually write

Comment: Thanks for the info! As mentioned above, Yes I am not using it correctly. When i don't know something I tend to make a new .py file, import the module i do not know well, use dir, see what it offers, and explore from there using help() and try to learn something new! I have a bunch of such py files for different modules and I comment out what I learnt using multi line strings. Guess I should use the command line more for these kinds of things!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what you wrote. You can also use a plain `dir()` to check what's in the current namespace, but it returns only a list of strings and you already have locals() which gives a bit more information.

```
def g():
    a = 1
    def b():
        pass
    class C:
        ....
    print(locals())
    print(dir())

>>> g()
{'a': 1, 'b': <function g.<locals>.b at 0x7f256c761630>, 'B': <class '__main__.g.<locals>.B'>}
['B', 'a', 'b']
```